# How can i remove script tag, which is inside html

Tags: javascript, html, google-analytics

i am trying to remove this script tag which is in html, it is used for google analytics, i want to this script to be removed when used does not accept cookies.

```
<script>     
var _gaq = _gaq || [];
         _gaq.push(['_setAccount', 'UA-46776072-1']);
         _gaq.push(['_setDomainName', 'av.gov.mk']);
         _gaq.push(['_trackPageview']);

        (function () {
             var ga = document.createElement('script'); ga.type = 
        'text/javascript'; ga.async = true;
             ga.src = ('https:' == document.location.protocol ? 'https://ssl' 
         : 'http://www') + '.google-analytics.com/ga.js';
             var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; 
        s.parentNode.insertBefore(ga, s);
         })();
     };
</script>
```

Comment: Removing it won't really help. It's too late. It will have already executed. You need to add it only if the user grants permission.

Comment: do it other way instead of removing add only if user approves

Comment: i think a better way is adding (running) this code after the user was accepting Cookies.

Comment: var cookieValue = $.cookie("gdpr");
     if (cookieValue === undefined) {
         $('.gdpr').fadeIn();
 }
 else if(cookieValue == 0){
  
 }
    else if (cookieValue == 1){
   //here is the script for the tag
         })();
  };

i am trying to solve in script , but even if cookies is 0 which is false, still google tag assistant found that there is code for google analytics

Comment: `if(cookieValue == 1)` is no valid JavaScript.. it should be `if(cookieValue)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put the GA script in a function that will be called after accepting cookies.

```js
function startGA(source) {
  document.getElementById(window.event.srcElement.id).style.display = "none";
  alert("Google Analytics script will be rendered now!")
  var _gaq = _gaq || [];
  _gaq.push(['_setAccount', 'UA-46776072-1']);
  _gaq.push(['_setDomainName', 'av.gov.mk']);
  _gaq.push(['_trackPageview']);

  (function() {
    var ga = document.createElement('script');
    ga.type =
      'text/javascript';
    ga.async = true;
    ga.src = ('https:' == document.location.protocol ? 'https://ssl' :
      'http://www') + '.google-analytics.com/ga.js';
    var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
    s.parentNode.insertBefore(ga, s);
  })();
}
```

```html
<input type="button" id="acceptCookies" value="Accept Cookies" onclick="startGA(this)" />
```

Comment: note that you shold not offer the acception by a checkbox like in this example. The user will think he could opt-out again, but this will not be possible. Also in this example the code will rerun every time the checkbox is unchecked and checked again. Do it using a button which will be removed after accepting.

Comment: Edited my answer. It's a button now